# changing a static date range into a dynamic date range in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to replace a static date range into a dynamic range. Currently I am using    `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$E$3:E$325,"IT/TWE",Referrals!$A$3:$A$325,"<11/1/15")` &    `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$E$3:$E$325, "IT/TWE", Referrals!$A$3:$A$325, ">=11/1/15", Referrals!$A$3:$A$325, "<=11/30/15")`.  ***Referrals!$A$3:$A$325*** is the date column & the date is entered by the user. In the past I would change the year manually. The second formula is the same for the other 10 months. Is it possible to do what I am asking? I have found various things related to dynamic ranges, but nit related to dates.

Comment: What are you asking? How can you set up a dynamic date...where? You mean so the user can choose a day, such as `11/1/15` and it'll check against that date?

Comment: I am trying to have the system change the date automatically from 11/1/15 to 11/1/16 .

Comment: You could do find/replace with the formula. Or set that part of your formula to a cell reference and just update that single cell,no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the year broken up into 6 columns & 6 rows on another sheet.  One row is for the month title & 2 rows are for the dates. I.e. October's title is in cell K5, October 1 is in Cell K6, & October 31st is in cell K7. The other months are the same except for the cell location & that they are based on cells K6 &K7. Here are the 2 formulas:    `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$E$3:E$325,"IT/TWE",Referrals!$A$3:$A$325,"<"&'Month Source'!K6)` &    `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$E$3:$E$325, "IT/TWE", Referrals!$A$3:$A$325, ">="&'Month Source'!L6,$A$3:$A$325,"<="&'Month Source'!L7)`.